# React JS import for navigating 3 folder up

Tags: reactjs

```
src
 ---COMPONENT
       ---UI
          card.js
       ---API
           ---JS
              --display.js
           ---CSS
              --display.css
```

Need to traverse from JS folder to UI
means, basically need to move 3 folder up. In display.js, need to import card.js

```
Tried with .../UI/card, but this did not work
```

Comment: `.../UI/card` ----> `../../card`

Comment: didnot work, I think,  this will take the evaluated path as \src\components\card

Answer (score 2):

Navigation to 3 folder up will not work with three dot in react, just like it works for 2 folder up navigation,

So, for 3 folder up navigation, every time you go up 2 folers, you need to go down 1 to continue.

```
 '../../../components/UI/Card'
```

another way

```
'../../UI/Card'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by only putting  ../UI/card
You'll have to go back two step up only that's why it didn't work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).